# dijit.form.FilteringSelect does not display any value

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I create a filtering select like so:

```
var lensMapServiceFS = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
 displayedValue: this.layerNames[0],
 value: this.layerNames[0],
 name: "lensMapServiceFS", 
 required: false,
 store: lensMapServiceOptions, 
 searchAttr: "name",
 style: {'width': '100px', 'fontSize': '8pt'}
}, this.id + ".lensMapService");
```

But when my page loads, nothing is displayed in the filtering select. All the values from my store display when you cilck the drop down but nothing is actually displayed in the filtering select. If I call getValue() or getDisplayedValue() from the firebug or chorme console the correct value is returned. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be a simple css issue. The value was actually there, but the text color was white on a white background. I added 'color': '#444' to the style property in the constructor and all is well.